# Finding a Specific Character in SQL Statement

Tags: postgresql

Is there a way I can find a certain character using `LIKE` keyword?

For example, let's say I have the following values in `COL1`:

```
1.75
5.50
5.67
```

I want to write a SQL statement that only returns values from `COL1` where the second character AFTER the decimal is a zero (regardless of what the rest of the number says.)

Comment: Is `Col1` number or string?

Comment: Col1 is a string, but it can be a number. I can transform it from one to the other if I need to. I am using a BI tool.

Comment: And is one or more `.` possible?

Comment: No. Each value goes in this format: "#.##"  (without the quotations)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Each value goes in this format: "#.##"

Then you could use wildcards `%` and `_`:

- an underscore **`_`** in pattern stands for (matches) any single character;
- a percent sign **`%`** matches any sequence of zero or more characters.

Query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tab 
WHERE col1 LIKE '%._0%';
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/c3b18/1/0)**</kbd>

Output:

```
╔══════╗
║ col1 ║
╠══════╣
║ 5.50 ║
╚══════╝
```

---

If values are only numbers (with two places only) you could use simple modulo division:

```
SELECT *
FROM tab 
WHERE col1 % 0.1 = 0;
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo2`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/8f47a/1/0)**</kbd>